# bash discard/edit part of glob (script fails when part of glob not found)

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I'm writing a script in BASH which basically acts like a simplified gmake & package builder. It only supports one langauge; this is by design. I do not intend to publish this script, as it is intended for local use only.

I've mostly got it working right. On more complicated projects, it handled everything fine. A problem came up when doing a simple test program.

The script builds up «args» to sane defaults with basic parameters. Regardless of the "mode", the script always executes a line with the following form:

```
«compiler» «args» *.«ext»
```

Given that the supported language (Ada) has two file extensions the following glob is used in compiling as «ext»:

```
*.{ads,adb}
```

When both extensions exist, as would be expected in larger projects, everything is fine. But the script fails, and compilation doesn't occur, when only one of the extensions exists in $PWD.

I'm rather confused by this, because a "clean mode" exists, which just does:

```
rm *.{ali,o,so}
```

and this works even if some of the listed extensions do not exist in $PWD.

I could call the compiler twice, passing one extension first, if files for that exist, and then passing the other extension likewise. This however causes compilation to occur twice for many files, which is an obvious inefficiency.

I'm thinking it would be possible to build a glob early in the script of what extensions exist in $PWD, and then pass the glob to the compiler. However, I have absolutely no idea how one could accomplish this. Some attempts have bash complaining that the command "*.{adb,ads}" couldn't be found. This really took me for a suprise, as I was essentially just doing:

```
«compiler» «args» $FoundFiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion turns `*.{adb,ads}` into two words, `*.adb` and `*.ads`. Then, each of those are (independently) glob-expanded. If glob-expansion fails, then the glob is passed unmodified, rather than being deleted. For example, if you had no files with extension `ads`, you might end up trying to compile `f1.adb f2.adb *.ads`. Since the last of those doesn't exist, the compiler will complain.

The exact same thing happens with `rm *.{ali,o,so}` and `rm` will complain and stop if one of the patterns gets passed through unmodified. But if the command is really `rm -f *.{ali,o,so}`, then it will execute just fine because the `-f` flag tells `rm` to ignore missing files (amongst other things).

You can modify bash's handling of unmatched globs by setting the `nullglob` shell option (`shopt -s nullglob`); with that option set, unmatched globs are removed from the word list instead of being passed through unmodified.

However, in this particular case you could also use

```
compile *.ad[bs]
```

which is a single glob with the same matches as the brace-expanded pair of globs. This, too, will be passed through unmodified if it doesn't match anything, but that would mean that there are no Ada files at all, which should trigger an error message. With `nullglob` set, the end result would be to call the compiler with no arguments; that will probably also produce an error message, but some utilities will process standard input if they are not provided any arguments, and you have to be careful with `nullglob` in such cases.

Comment: Read the entire BASH manual and must have missed bracket globs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nullglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
compiler other_args *.{ads,adb}
```

#### Explanation

Let's use a directory that has one .ads file but no .adb files:

```
$ echo *.{ads,adb}
1.ads *.adb
```

By default, if no file matches a glob, bash will return the glob itself, in this case `*.adb`.  The `nullglob` option changes that and a glob with no matches will be omitted.  Thus:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo *.{ads,adb}
1.ads
```

To reset nullglob to off, use:

```
shopt -u nullglob
```